# Question about a single photon's wave

Tags: quantum-mechanics, newtonian-mechanics, photons

Assume you have a single photon generator in empty space surrounded by a spherical array of many detectors each of which is 10 light seconds from the generator.  A single photon is generated.  I assume that the wave equation would describe a spherical propagation of the wave outward from its source.  If a photon is detected by one element in the detector array, does the wave function instantly collapse?  If a spherical wave is generated, how does the wave on the opposite side of the array instantly "know" the photon has been detected? Does the answer involve quantum entanglement?

Comment: There is no wave with one photon. A single photon would be detected in one spot after traveling directly from the source.

Comment: of course there is. A single photon does certainly have a wave-function in the quantum sense

Comment: @Simon  A wave function is only a mathematical formula. In reality the photon travels from source to detector. The photon has a speed, direction, polarization and a frequency. That’s it

Comment: @BillAlsept I am sorry, but you are mistaken. In quantum mechanics, photons are described by wave-functions. A photon IS a wave function. A photon is not a classical point-particle with well-defined position/speed/etc. Heisenbergs uncertainty principle is not a matter of incomplete information, its really a fundamental property of the wave-function.

Comment: @Simon your right, a photon is only described by a wave-function. The OPs question highlights the problem you have if you consider the wave function a physical thing.

Comment: @BillAlsept No, there is no problem. Quantum mechanics works. I did just go over your "single edge certainty" theory (on your website). After a coarse reading I would say it is a nice work and provides something like a particle version of classical electrodynamics (which is enough to derive the patterns in slit-experiments). But it does not work for actual quantum phenomena. This discussion would lead far away from the original question of course. But if you are interested, we can discuss it somewhere else (im currently finishing my phd in theoretical particle physics. I hope I know my stuff)

Comment: I agree the math of quantum mechanics works. That math fits a real physical model. After all we know something really happens. A particle model can account for any quantum phenomena and Yes I would be interested in discussing this somewhere else. Thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124520/discussion-between-simon-and-bill-alsept).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

("Collaps of the wave function" is a concept in the Copenhagen interpretation of quantum mechanics, so I will stick to that. In other interpretations - such as many-worlds - the explanation would be different, though all results are of course the same)

Yes, the wave function collapses when you measure the particle at one point. This does indeed mean that the wave function on the opposite side immediately "knows" that it isn't there. This does seem to violate special relativity, because this "signal" traveled faster than light. In fact it does not violate anything, because this signal does not carry information from one side to the other (after all, the location where the photon is measured is random). But still, it is quite weird and means that physics is not really "local" in a strong sense. This is called the "EPR paradoxon" (google it. Its quite fascinating).

Usually, the word "entanglement" is used if the states of two (or more) particles are correlated with each other. So this setting with a single photon would not be called entanglement, even though its essentially the same phenomenon. And you can easily get an entangled state out of this setting: If you let the photon be detected by one of the detectors, but you dont look at them (impossible in practice, but fine as a thought experiment). Then the states of the detectors (which are both in a superposition between "I have detected the photon" and "I have not detected the photon) are entangled with each other. This collapses once you look at one of the detectors to see which it is.

Comment: Thank you very much for your clear and thoughtful answer.  This is indeed "weird."  I have been reading Sean Carroll's book on the Higgs particle.  He puts forth the analogy that a particle (field disturbance) is like a ripple in water.  However, this analogy only goes so far (as I'm sure Sean knows).  Imagine dropping a stone into a quiet pond with the drop site surrounded by many bobbers that detect the passage of the wave (by moving up and down).  It doesn't happen that the movement of one bobber instantly "flattens" the wave in the rest of the pond. Strange quantum world.

Comment: (continued. . . ) This all just goes to show how our intuition derived from watching events in the macroscopic world fails in the quantum realm.

Answer (score 0):

Wave function collapse is not a physical phenomenon. It does not happen. In this example there is a spherical wave, which describes the probability that photons reach the detectors. If the wave intensity is low and you don't integrate over along time, then it may be that only one photon is detected, with equal probability, by any of the detectors.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  You make a good point.  The wave function is not to be viewed as a physical phenomenon (like the wave front of a wave on water). As Sean Carroll says in his book on the Higgs: "There is no such thing as where the particle is, really."  I guess you can also say there is no such thing as where the wave front of the wave function is, really (until it is detected).  Thanks again.